# C: Store a large "virtual" array

Tags: c

I am translating a 32 bit CPU emulator from python to C.

32 bit address space ==> 4GB of memory, but that is more memory than a lot of machines can handle. For this reason in the Python emulator, I used a dict, because it gave access to the entire address space, but only a small subset would be used at once.

In C, I would like to preserve access to the whole address space (since a C-based emulator would be able to read or write to the whole address space in a matter of seconds) but keep the memory manageable (so no 4gb array), and maintain high performance(the main reason for rewriting the emulator in c).

One solution I have thought of is creating a paging system, so only a small amount of the array is stored in memory and the rest on disk. How could I implement this (I am new to C), and are there any better solutions?

Comment: you could implement an hash table (read dict) where the key is the high part of the memory address and the low part is the offset inside the page. Each key points to a chunk of memory

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking into [`mmap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) and [memory-mapped storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).